# ExpressionEngine on PHP7

Tags: php, performance, compatibility

**PHP 7 Release Candidate 7** [came out](http://php.net/archive/2015.php#id2015-11-12-1) today.

[Rasmus Lerdorf](https://twitter.com/@rasmus) has been [giving talks](http://talks.php.net/taiwan15#/) on the advantages of PHP7 including benchmarking against many popular PHP applications -- for example here's [the benchmark for WordPress](http://talks.php.net/taiwan15#/wpbench).  His talks also include [a request](http://talks.php.net/taiwan15#/php_contribute) for PHP users to run their own tests/benchmarks against their own code.

Questions:

Has anyone tried EE3 or EE2 on this new version of PHP?

Has EllisLab made any comment regarding EE on PHP7?

Has anyone tried benchmarking EE on PHP7 according to Ras' instructions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning a statement from EllisLab, they posted a blog-entry on 13th April, 2016 telling that EE2 and EE3 are PHP 7-compatible: https://ellislab.com/blog/entry/time-to-upgrade-php

Comment: Which versions of EE 2 are compatible?

Answer (score 2):

I just gave it a shot and it looked like the install worked fine, but the control panel loaded up with a bunch of errors. It looked like they could likely have been suppressed by turning off E_NOTICE or changing E_STRICT in error reporting since they didn't look like errors that would stop anything from working.

Answer (score 2):

Been running EE3 (3.3.3) with php7, and it runs smooth as a baby's butt.

There are a whole lot of problems with add-ons tho I've realised.

- Solstice TAG throws a nasty error making it impossible to add new entries.
- DataGrab is not working (Well, the UI is, but no imports are made, and no import-setups can be saved).

Don't know about any other add-ons (except Stash, which works, of course), since we stopped development until PHP has been downgraded.

So, if you run **no** add-ons, upgrade your PHP.
If you are relying on add-ons, be *very very* careful.

Answer (score 1):

I have run a site locally on PHP 7 without any problems. EE usually only requires a minimal version of PHP. As I've said, no issues so far.

Comment: What version of EE are you running under PHP7?

Comment: @AllInOne 3.0.5. I have no reason to believe that 2.10.1 wouldn't work, but I haven't tried myself.

Answer (score 0):

We are just trying to run a older version of EE on PHP7.

The only major issue we are encountering is that all the form submissions are setting the local date to 1969-12-31 23:59, although that only appears to be on form submission rather than actually on when its running. For example if I add {entry_date} into a form page, when you load the page it will display the correct result, after you hit submit, it will change to 1969-12-31 23:59.

EE is 2.5.3, unfortunately too much custom code in it to upgrade it.

If anyone happens to know what is causing this, it would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Hi Drenzul.  Thanks for the info.  I suggest you post a new question about your trouble and link to it from here.

Comment: Was going to if I can't find the answer, I'm trying to dig into it now :)

If I work it out I'll post how to fix.

Comment: It was a parameter been passed to GMDate function that had an additional function been passed to it which resulted in it failing and returning -1 but not actually erroring.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has hit this, the `string_to_timestamp` function in `Localize.php` is the problem. `convert_human_date_to_gmt` is returning back an invalid date so it returns 0 date (adjusted for GMT)